# Trying to pass an array to another component that I'm receiving through an async function

Tags: reactjs, async-await

Essentially I have a page where I map out a list of files and after the user is down I call them from an api. I then package the file with other meta data. However my issue is that when I pass back my package to my frontend I am getting an error about passing back a promise. I'm using await on async function I know this is causing a promise to be passed to my variable but I am unsure how else to pass back my file with its meta data. Any suggestions for different approaches or a more proper way to use async functions in order to achieve my goal?

Code:

```
const gatherFileNames = async() =>{
   let fams = defineFams()
   let finishedCells = []
   finishedCells = await QueryFiles(fams)

   return finishedCells
}


export default async function GenerateGraphPage(){
   let allCells = await gatherFileNames()

   return(
      <div>
        <DefineHeader />
        <CellGraph cells = {allCells}/>
       </div>
   );
 }
```

Notes:

- finishedCells is holding an array of objects

Completed Code for reference:

```
export default function GenerateGraphPage(){

const [data, setData] = useState();

useEffect(()=>{
    const getData = async() => {
        const fileData = await gatherFileNames()
        setData(fileData)
        console.log(fileData)
    }
    getData()
},[])


return(
    <div>
        <DefineHeader />
        <CellGraph cells={data}/>
    </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Use state to store the value and render the component dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming QueryFiles returns a promsie this might be what you are looking for, I also refactored your code a little bit, I hope you don't mind.

```
const gatherFileNames = () =>{
   return QueryFiles(defineFams())
   //no async
}
```

If someone knows how the async works in this example feel free to copy this answer to explain it. Because I don't know the technical terms but this worked for me.

```
export default async function GenerateGraphPage(){
   let allCells = await gatherFileNames()
   //async
   return(
      <div>
        <DefineHeader />
        <CellGraph cells={allCells}/>
       </div>
   );
 }
```

I would also recommend using useState and a useEffect hook to call gatherFileNames so it isn't called on every render which could slow your website down.

```
export default async function GenerateGraphPage(){

const [data, setData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
   let FileData = [];
   const getData = async () => {
      //to use await in a useEffect you will need to make an async function
      // and call it first in the useEffect
      fileData = await gatherFileNames(); 
      }
      getData();
      // getData called here before handling any other synchronous logic
      setData(fileData)
   }, []) //this empty array means this useEffect will run once when the page loads
          //if you put 'dependencies here such as [data,setData]' 
          //this will run everytime data and setData are used
   return(
      <div>
        <DefineHeader />
        <CellGraph cells={data}/>
        // using data here
       </div>
   );
 }
```